# CocoaPods and Carthage

Tags: swift, cocoapods, carthage

I had a project with both Carthage and Cocoapods. They both have one common dependency (PureLayout, to be precise). Strange, but project compiles fine without any errors about class redeclaration, etc.
So the question is: why it works and which version of dependency is actually used when I call PureLayout's methods – Carthage's or Cocoapods' one?

Comment: here is the good explanation about https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/cocoapods-vs-carthage-675633e89c3e

Answer (score 15):

`Carthage` and `CocoaPods` are very different in terms of building the dependencies and integrating them in the project.

CocoaPods is centralized dependency manager and it will build your dependencies and integrate them directly in the project by creating new `.xcworkspace` workspace. This means that you get access to the build dependencies right after building.

Carthage on the other hand is decentralized dependency manager and it leaves you with the task of integrating the dependencies into your project. Carthage builds the frameworks specified in `Cartfile` and moves them to `Carthage/Builds` folder. After the build process it's up to you to integrate and manage the dependencies.

In your case, when you build your `PureLayout` dependency with CocoaPods and Carthage, CocoaPods integrated it to project and Carthage left you with builds in `Carthage/Builds` which means that you used only CocoaPods build version of `PureLayout`.

Also, it's a bad practice to use multiple package/dependency managers. You should stick to the one and be comfortable with it.

Comment: Yes, if I didn't link project with framework built by Carthage there will be no surprise that Cocoapods version works. But I did. It's in Linked Frameworks and Libraries section now. That's why I'm surprised.

Answer (score 5):

**iOS Dependency manager**

When you do not use a `Dependency manager` as a developer you are responsible for:

- finding a dependency
- resolving a dependency graph and versioning
- downloading the sources
- add the dependency into Xcode

And when you decide to upgrade the dependency you should start this process from the beginning

`Dependency manager` is a tool that helps user to add a dependency into a project with a minimum affords

[**`CocoaPods`**](https://cocoapods.org/)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877) is an [open-source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods), **centralised** dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects which is being written on Ruby. It Supports `Dynamic Frameworks` and `Static Libraries`[<sup>[timeline]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257384/4770877)

Notes:

- CocoaPods needs to have a workspace
- A consumer project does not have a clean view of dependencies <Pods_target-name.framework>
- All dependencies are **rebuild** every time when you build the project. It increases build time as a workaround take a look at [cocoapods-binary](https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html)
- It is not possible to use different pod versions in the same workspace

  ```
  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
  ```

**`Carthage`**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397563/4770877) is an [open-source](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), **decentralised** dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects which is being written on Swift. It supports `Dynamic Frameworks` and `Static Libraries`

Notes:

- As a consumer project developer you are responsible for setup Xcode with a dependency. It creates some extra steps in IDE
- As a dependency developer you do not have some instruments(e.g. subspecs)

**`Swift Package Manager(SPM)`**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910223/4770877) is an [open-source](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager), **decentralised**  dependency manager which is being written on Swift. It supports Dynamic and Static library. `.xcodeproj` is not used. If you want to distribute closed-source(binary framework) you should use `XCFramework`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181295/4770877)

*`CocoaPods` by default builds open-source pods every time(after clean or any unknown reason) which increase build time(but you can use [`cocoapods-binary`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html)), `Carthage` and `SPM` pre-builds framework by default.

*closed-source allows you to close the source code and save build time, but can have issues with `ABI stability`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271017/4770877)